# How can I prevent my laptop auto suspend (due to critically low battery) from looping?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, battery

I have an Acer Aspire 5750G on Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I've got a problem:

Battery critically low > suspend > wake up instantly (I don't touch ANYTHING) > suspend > wake up.... power outage > dead.

I've posted a syslog on pastebin of the PC doing this crazy thing

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5625069/

Comment: This is a known bug even in 14.04, can you please mark this as "This bug affects me" and post your log?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1395258

Comment: Anyway, you should not use suspend when having critically low battery, because a suspended system still needs energy (because it stores its status in RAM which needs to be refreshed every few msecs), otherwise it is like if you switch of a running system. You should use hibernation if your machine supports this or shut down, but maybe you rather want it to do nothing so you can save everything and shut down manually?